# Added content not showing up

Tags: ee2

I'm very new to ExpressionEngine and am currently dealing with updating an existing site. I've been having problems getting new content to show up where its supposed to. I've added content that is the same structure and assigned to the same channel as the current content, but it doesn't show up on the page. I'm really confused since I thought this was supposed to be pretty straightforward. The channel I'm trying to add to is called brand-merchandise here is the design view of the page I'm having problems with: (brands/listing-template)

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{segment_1}" category="{last_segment_category_id}" dynamic="no" orderby="date" sort="dsc"}
<div class="isotope-item post span8">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
        {exp:channel_images:images entry_id="{entry_id}" limit="1"}
            <div class="thumbnail post-media">
                <div id="{image:entry_id}" class="carousel slide fadeLeft">
                    <!-- Carousel items -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner"> 
                        {product_images}
                           <div class="{if {image:count} == 1}active item{if:else}item{/if}">
                               <img src="{image:url:medium}" alt="{image:title}" />
                           </div>
                        {/product_images}
                    </div>
                    <!-- Carousel nav -->
                    {product_images}
                       {if {image:total} > 1}
                          <a class="carousel-control left" href="#{image:entry_id}" data-slide="prev"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></a>
                          <a class="carousel-control right" href="#{image:entry_id}" data-slide="next"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>
                       {if:else}
                          {if segment_1 != "retail-products"}
                             <div class="thumbnail-hover">
                                <a href="{page_url}"></a>
                             </div>
                          {/if}
                       {/if}
                    {/product_images}
                </div>
            </div>
        {/exp:channel_images:images}                                                                             
     </div>

     <div class="span4">
         <div class="post-content">
             <div class="post-title">
                 <h2>{title}</h2><br>
             </div>


             <div class="post-excerpt">
                {product_description}<br><br>
             </div>

             {if segment_1 != "retail-products"}
                <div class="stylish-button">
                    <a href="{page_url}">view work</a>
                </div>
             {/if}
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Are you making sure your new Channel Entries have a status that is not set to "Closed" or "Draft"?

Answer (score 0):

To the exp:channel:entries tag, you need to add status="not closed" or any other custom statuses you might have defined.